# CPLEX python API warmstart

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex

I'm trying to implement a warmstart in CPLEX python API.

I know I have to use the following function:

```
set_start(self, col_status, row_status, col_primal, row_primal, col_dual, row_dual)
```

Let's assume that I have five variables ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"] and I want to assigned them the following values [0, 1, 0, 0, 1] for the warmstart.

I would like to do something like:

```
set_start(col_status=[],
          row_status=[],
          col_primal=["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"],
          row_primal=[0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
          col_dual=[],
          row_dual=[])
```

but in the documentation it's written that:

> Each entry of col_primal and row_primal must be a float specifying the
>   starting primal values for the columns and rows, respectively.

and I don't understand why.

How can I do it in practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation for [set_start](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.InitialInterface-class.html#set_start) it also says:

> The arguments col_status, col_primal, and col_dual are **lists that
>   either have length equal to the number of variables or are empty**. If
>   col_status is empty, then row_status must also be empty. If col_primal
>   is empty, then row_primal must also be empty.

For example, we can call `set_status`, like so:

```
>>> import cplex
>>> c = cplex.Cplex()
>>> indices = c.variables.add(names=["x" + str(i) for i in range(5)])
>>> c.start.set_start(col_status=[],
...                   row_status=[],
...                   col_primal=[0., 1., 0., 0., 1],
...                   row_primal=[],
...                   col_dual=[],
...                   row_dual=[])
```

With the example, note that the variable indices that correspond with `["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"]` are `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, and that there are a total of `5` variables in the model. The values passed to `col_primal` must also correspond with that list of indices (e.g., for variable with index 0, the value is 0.0, for variable with index 1, the value is 1.0, etc.).